# How to throw error from custom class nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, error-handling

I'm trying to create a global error handler in node js with typescript. I have created some custom classes which extends error class something like this:-

**custom class**

```
export abstract class CustomError extends Error {
  abstract statusCode: number;
  abstract errorMessage: string;
  abstract data: unknown;
  constructor() {
    super();
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CustomError.prototype);
  }

  abstract serializeError(): { message: string; fields?: string }[] | string;
}
```

**Bad request error class**

```
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';

import { CustomError } from './custom.error';

class BadRequestException extends CustomError {
  statusCode = StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST;
  errorMessage: string;
  data: any;

  constructor(errorMessage?: string) {
    super();
    // set default value
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage || 'Bad Request';

    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, BadRequestException.prototype);
  }

  serializeError() {
    return this.errorMessage;
  }
}

export default BadRequestException;
```

**server.js**

```
dotenv.config();
const app: Express = express();

app.use('/', routes);
app.use(globalErrorHandler);
export default app;
```

**routes.ts**

```
import express from 'express';
import UserController from '../controller/user/user-controller';
import NotFoundException from '../exception/not-found-exception';
import authorizationMiddleware from '../middleware/authorization-middleware';

const router = express.Router();

// users routes
router.post('/user/create', UserController.createUser);
router.get('/user/profile/:key', UserController.getProfile);
router.get('/user/directus', UserController.getDirectUs);

router.use('*', () => {
  throw new NotFoundException();
});

export default router;
```

**controller.ts**

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';
import { directus } from '../../config/directus-confgi';
import BadRequestException from '../../exception/bad-request-exception';
import { USER } from '../../interface/user-interface';
import UserService from './user.service';

class UserController {
 
  // getting user profile
  static async getDirectUs(request: Request, response: Response) {
    try {
      const user = await directus.items('articles').readOne(15);

      response.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ user });
    } catch (error: any) {
      throw new BadRequestException(error.message);
    }
  }
}

export default UserController;
```

**Global Error Handler**

```
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { CustomError } from '../exception/custom.error';

const globalErrorHandler = (err: any, req: Request, res: Response,next:NextFunction) => {
  if (err instanceof CustomError) {
    const error: { message: string; errors?: any } = {
      message: err.errorMessage ? req.body.i18nObj.__(err.errorMessage) : '',
    };

    if (err.data) error.errors = err.serializeError();

    return res.status(err.statusCode).json(error);
  }

  res.status(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
    message: err.message
      ? err.message
      : req.body.i18nObj.__('MESSAGES.UNABLE_COMPLETE_REQUEST'),
    error: { message: err.message, err },
  });
};

export default globalErrorHandler;
```

I'm getting errors in my controller catch block and bad-request error class but after that my global error handler middleware function is not able to get this error, in a result, I'm not able to send this error as a response.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or how can call my middleware function without throwing an actual error from the controller I want to use my custom error class to formate error and status code.

Comment: ya I did, but it still not working getting unhandledRejection in my console

Comment: What version of Express are you using?

Comment: I'm using express 4.18.1

Answer (score 1):

In Express v4, you need to manually call `next()` in async controllers in order for error handling middleware to work.

> [**Catching Errors**](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)
>
> For errors returned from asynchronous functions invoked by route handlers and middleware, you must pass them to the next() function, where Express will catch and process them.

```ts
class UserController {
  // getting user profile
  static async getDirectUs(
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ) {
    try {
      const user = await directus.items("articles").readOne(15);

      response.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ user });
    } catch (error: any) {
      // pass the custom error to `next()`
      next(new BadRequestException(error.message));
    }
  }
}
```

From Express v5 you won't have to do this

> Starting with Express 5, route handlers and middleware that return a Promise will call next(value) automatically when they reject or throw an error