# Express error handler middleware not being called when an error is thrown and causing the application to crash

Tags: express, error-handling, middleware

I want the express error handling middleware to be called when an error is thrown. This is the error handling middleware:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

export const errorHandler = (
    err: Error,
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
) => {
    console.log(`Something went wrong ${err}`);

    res.status(400).send({
        message: "Something went wrong",
    });
};
```

And I am importing it in my index.ts and using after all route handlers like so:

```
 import express from "express";
import { json } from "body-parser";

import { leadRouter } from "./routes/lead";
import { errorHandler } from "./middlewares/error-handler";

const app = express();
app.use(json());

app.use(leadRouter);

app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

And here is where the error is thrown when the email is not valid:

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import { body, validationResult } from "express-validator";

const router = express.Router();

router.post(
    "/lead",
    [
        body("email").isEmail().withMessage("Email must be valid"),
        body("name").notEmpty().withMessage("A name has to be provided"),
    ],
    async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Error("Invalid Email");
        }

        const { email, name } = req.body;

        console.log("Creating a user...");

        res.send({});
    }
);

export { router as leadRouter };
```

What is happening is that the server crashes. This is from the command line: [image]

Comment: Unless you're using Express v5, you need to call `next()` in order to invoke the error handler. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73617102/283366)